# MSP430FR5xxx CRC in info block

Tags: microcontroller, msp430, texas-instruments

What is the "CRC value" in the info block of MSP430FR5959 (address 01A02h)?

All specs just say "CRC value" and "per unit". But what is the actual data being checksummed? Device ID? Firmware? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

This [User's Guide (SLAU367M)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau367m/slau367m.pdf) has some clues in section 1.14.  Table 6-62 in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430fr5959.pdf) says that the CRC length value is 6, which is the same as the Info length value.  And the User's Guide section 1.14.1 explains that Info Length value of 6 means 2^6 = 64 32-bit words or 256 bytes.  So I suspect the CRC length is also 256 bytes.  And I interpret section 1.14.2 to say that Info length (and presumably CRC length) start from address 0x1A08.  So my guess is that the CRC value is calculated over the 256 bytes starting at address 0x1A08.